# is it available to get latitude and longitude in USSD application

Tags: javascript, geolocation, ussd

is it available to get latitude and longitude in USSD application,or in short user location in USSD.
i have used JavaScript to code the USSD but cant get location please help....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer**: no, not possible

**Longer answer**: What you are coding in js is the server part while, I believe, you would like to get the position of the subscriber who is actually issuing USSD requests. USSD request leave the phone of the sub and arrive to the telco' core network which then route it to the application server, your js backend. The USSD request doesn't carry any location information so you can't get the longitude and latitude. However, your telco knows the serving cell on which the sub is attached at the moment the USSD request is issued so you *might* know at least the position of that cell: it's not a very precise location, but for some applications that's better than nothing. However, unless your system is part of telcos VAS portfolio, they would never provide you with that information for ethical reasons, typically the protection of private life of their subscribers